# Merge entries in XML

Tags: php, xml, bash, xslt

I have a XML containing products and I need to somehow merge to one entry:

```
<SHOPITEM>
        <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
        <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>029,00</CODE>
        <COLOR>black / yellow</COLOR>
</SHOPITEM>
<SHOPITEM>
        <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
        <FRAMESIZE>LD</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>029,01</CODE>
        <COLOR>black / yellow</COLOR>
</SHOPITEM>
<SHOPITEM>
        <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
        <FRAMESIZE>LD</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>029,03</CODE>
        <COLOR>green / white</COLOR>
</SHOPITEM>
<SHOPITEM>
        <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
        <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>029,04</CODE>
        <COLOR>green / white</COLOR>
</SHOPITEM>
```

The `<PRODUCT>` is same, what is change is the `<FRAMESIZE>, <CODE>, <COLOR>`.

Is there any way to get from this an usable data? The best would be in PHP, but also would be good to generate a new XML file which I can process in PHP:

```
<SHOPITEM>
        <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
        <FRAMESIZE1>MD</FRAMESIZE1>
        <CODE1>029,00</CODE1>
        <COLOR1>black / yellow</COLOR2>
        <FRAMESIZE2>LD</FRAMESIZE2>
        <CODE2>029,01</CODE2>
        <COLOR2>black / yellow</COLOR2>
        <FRAMESIZE3>LD</FRAMESIZE3>
        <CODE3>029,03</CODE3>
        <COLOR3>green / white</COLOR3>
        <FRAMESIZE4>MD</FRAMESIZE4>
        <CODE4>029,04</CODE4>
        <COLOR4>green / white</COLOR4>
</SHOPITEM>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the topic. Maybe this will help you:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT and http://php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I **strongly** recommend you figure out an XSLT solution - glenn jackman

I can only second that. So, here is your XSLT solution. However, the question is: Did you show a *representative* XML sample or are there several different `PRODUCT` elements in your *real* XML data?

Also, naming elements `CODE1`, `CODE2` and so on can be done, but I would (again, strongly) recommend not to do it. I'm glad to add in this detail, but first clarify if you *really* need this crippling naming convention or if you can use attributes instead:

```
<CODE n="1"/>
```

**XML Input**

As suggested by Glenn already, there must be a single outermost element to make your input well-formed XML.

```
<root>
    <SHOPITEM>
            <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
            <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
            <CODE>029,00</CODE>
            <COLOR>black / yellow</COLOR>
    </SHOPITEM>
    <SHOPITEM>
            <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
            <FRAMESIZE>LD</FRAMESIZE>
            <CODE>029,01</CODE>
            <COLOR>black / yellow</COLOR>
    </SHOPITEM>
    <SHOPITEM>
            <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
            <FRAMESIZE>LD</FRAMESIZE>
            <CODE>029,03</CODE>
            <COLOR>green / white</COLOR>
    </SHOPITEM>
    <SHOPITEM>
            <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
            <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
            <CODE>029,04</CODE>
            <COLOR>green / white</COLOR>
    </SHOPITEM>
</root>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet (1.0)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <SHOPITEM>
            <xsl:copy-of select="SHOPITEM[1]/PRODUCT"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="SHOPITEM/*[not(self::PRODUCT)]"/>
        </SHOPITEM>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<SHOPITEM>
   <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
   <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
   <CODE>029,00</CODE>
   <COLOR>black / yellow</COLOR>
   <FRAMESIZE>LD</FRAMESIZE>
   <CODE>029,01</CODE>
   <COLOR>black / yellow</COLOR>
   <FRAMESIZE>LD</FRAMESIZE>
   <CODE>029,03</CODE>
   <COLOR>green / white</COLOR>
   <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
   <CODE>029,04</CODE>
   <COLOR>green / white</COLOR>
</SHOPITEM>
```

---

**EDIT**:

> What I missed too, that there is many different  elements as Mathias asked.

**XML Input**

A more reasonable sample for testing, with more than one `PRODUCT`:

```
<root>
    <SHOPITEM>
            <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
            <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
            <CODE>029,00</CODE>
            <COLOR>black / yellow</COLOR>
    </SHOPITEM>
    <SHOPITEM>
            <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
            <FRAMESIZE>LD</FRAMESIZE>
            <CODE>029,01</CODE>
            <COLOR>black / yellow</COLOR>
    </SHOPITEM>
    <SHOPITEM>
            <PRODUCT>OTHER</PRODUCT>
            <FRAMESIZE>LD</FRAMESIZE>
            <CODE>029,03</CODE>
            <COLOR>green / white</COLOR>
    </SHOPITEM>
    <SHOPITEM>
            <PRODUCT>OTHER</PRODUCT>
            <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
            <CODE>029,04</CODE>
            <COLOR>green / white</COLOR>
    </SHOPITEM>
</root>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="prod" match="SHOPITEM" use="PRODUCT"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="SHOPITEM[generate-id() = generate-id(key('prod',PRODUCT)[1])]">
                <SHOPITEM>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="PRODUCT"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/root/SHOPITEM[PRODUCT = current()/PRODUCT]/*[not(self::PRODUCT)]"/>
                </SHOPITEM>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<root>
   <SHOPITEM>
      <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
      <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
      <CODE>029,00</CODE>
      <COLOR>black / yellow</COLOR>
      <FRAMESIZE>LD</FRAMESIZE>
      <CODE>029,01</CODE>
      <COLOR>black / yellow</COLOR>
   </SHOPITEM>
   <SHOPITEM>
      <PRODUCT>OTHER</PRODUCT>
      <FRAMESIZE>LD</FRAMESIZE>
      <CODE>029,03</CODE>
      <COLOR>green / white</COLOR>
      <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
      <CODE>029,04</CODE>
      <COLOR>green / white</COLOR>
   </SHOPITEM>
</root>
```

Comment: I hope you see this. :) This XLST method is looking very nice, but is there a way to make output like this? http://bit.ly/1E5maUp (use attributes on product variant elements)

Comment: @Adrian Is the output format something you have designed yourself? I would advise against it because it seems misleading that there is no `@id = 1`. In any case, you should never change your question by linking somewhere off-site. Either _edit_ your question to reflect what you _really_ wanted to ask. Or, accept one of the answers here, and post another question where you include _actual_ XML because we really need to see the _real_ problem, and use code from here at the starting point. In my opinion, you should go for option 2 because this post is already overly long.

Comment: you are right, I opened a new question and accepted your solution, because it is universal (XLST).

Answer (score 2):

My XSLT-fu is weak, but this produces your desired output (after wrapping your sample XML with a root tag):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//SHOPITEM[1]/PRODUCT' -n -m '//SHOPITEM' -v FRAMESIZE -n -v CODE -n -v COLOR -n file.xml | 
awk '
  BEGIN {print "<SHOPITEM>"} 
  END   {print "</SHOPITEM>"}
  NR==1 {print "  <PRODUCT>" $0 "</PRODUCT>"; next} 
  {
    n++;     t="FRAMESIZE"; printf "  <%s%d>%s</%s%d>\n", t, n, $0, t, n
    getline; t="CODE";      printf "  <%s%d>%s</%s%d>\n", t, n, $0, t, n
    getline; t="COLOR";     printf "  <%s%d>%s</%s%d>\n", t, n, $0, t, n
  }
'
```

```xml
<SHOPITEM>
  <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
  <FRAMESIZE1>MD</FRAMESIZE1>
  <CODE1>029,00</CODE1>
  <COLOR1>black / yellow</COLOR1>
  <FRAMESIZE2>LD</FRAMESIZE2>
  <CODE2>029,01</CODE2>
  <COLOR2>black / yellow</COLOR2>
  <FRAMESIZE3>LD</FRAMESIZE3>
  <CODE3>029,03</CODE3>
  <COLOR3>green / white</COLOR3>
  <FRAMESIZE4>MD</FRAMESIZE4>
  <CODE4>029,04</CODE4>
  <COLOR4>green / white</COLOR4>
</SHOPITEM>
```

---

In hindsight, this output format *may* be easier to process:

```
xmlstarlet ... file.xml | awk '
      BEGIN {print "<SHOPITEM>"; fmt="\t\t<%s>%s</%s>\n"} 
      END   {print "</SHOPITEM>"}
      NR==1 {print "\t<PRODUCT>" $0 "</PRODUCT>"; next} 
      {
        n++
        printf "\t<PRODUCT_ITEM id=\"%d\">\n", n
        t="FRAMESIZE"; printf fmt, t, $0, t; getline
        t="CODE";      printf fmt, t, $0, t; getline
        t="COLOR";     printf fmt, t, $0, t
        print "\t</PRODUCT_ITEM>"
      }
    '
```

```xml
<SHOPITEM>
    <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT_ITEM id="1">
        <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>029,00</CODE>
        <COLOR>black / yellow</COLOR>
    </PRODUCT_ITEM>
    <PRODUCT_ITEM id="2">
        <FRAMESIZE>LD</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>029,01</CODE>
        <COLOR>black / yellow</COLOR>
    </PRODUCT_ITEM>
    <PRODUCT_ITEM id="3">
        <FRAMESIZE>LD</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>029,03</CODE>
        <COLOR>green / white</COLOR>
    </PRODUCT_ITEM>
    <PRODUCT_ITEM id="4">
        <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>029,04</CODE>
        <COLOR>green / white</COLOR>
    </PRODUCT_ITEM>
</SHOPITEM>
```

Comment: Hi glenn, this awk solution looks fantastic. I missed some tags from the question, I tried to add missing tags to the command, without success: http://bit.ly/1xtJXHR, here are the new command with tags I missed: http://bit.ly/1sDKH1g

Comment: This solution absolutely relies on `xmlstarlet` to parse the XML. I **strongly** recommend you figure out an XSLT solution

Comment: I'd say so, too - XSLT is the right tool in my opinion. But +1 anyway, I wouldn't have thought that was possible in the shell. Thanks for the retag, btw!

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me. What I missed too, that there is many different <PRODUCT> elements as Mathias asked.

Comment: @Adrian If you do not add `@` in front of my name, I will not be notified of that mention. Please see the edit to my answer and tell me if that does what you need (also here:http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rMg/9).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution in XSLT 1.0 - which assumes that there can be multiple `<SHOPTITEM>` elements.

I have added a root element (`<root>`) because your input XML was not well-formed. You can also see/test the solution here: http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTk

Note that there is one template to match the first PRODUCT, which groups the data according to the name of the PRODUCT. And another template which handles alle occurences of the same PRODUCT which are not the first and simply does nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[not(PRODUCT = preceding::SHOPITEM/PRODUCT)]">
        <SHOPITEM>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::SHOPITEM[PRODUCT = current()/PRODUCT]/*[not(self::PRODUCT)]"/>
        </SHOPITEM>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[PRODUCT = preceding::SHOPITEM/PRODUCT]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

This is not the fastest solution, but it should work reasonably fast if your input xml is not too big.