# Merge entries in XML with XSLT

Tags: php, xml, xslt

Here is a snippet from my XML file, every product is an individual `<SHOPITEM>` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SHOP>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <CATEGORY>Full</CATEGORY>
        <WHEEL>27.5</WHEEL>
        <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>032,00</CODE>
        <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
        <COLOR>black / white</COLOR>
        <NOTE>Available 15.2.2015</NOTE>
        <URL></URL>
        <IMGURL1></IMGURL1>
        <IMGURL2></IMGURL2>
        <IMGURL3></IMGURL3>
        <PRICE>3199.99</PRICE>
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>


        <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
        <AVAILABLE>NO</AVAILABLE>
    </SHOPITEM>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <CATEGORY>Full</CATEGORY>
        <WHEEL>27.5</WHEEL>
        <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>032,99</CODE>
        <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
        <COLOR>red / green</COLOR>
        <NOTE>Available 15.2.2015</NOTE>
        <URL></URL>
        <IMGURL1></IMGURL1>
        <IMGURL2></IMGURL2>
        <IMGURL3></IMGURL3>
        <PRICE>3199.99</PRICE>
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>


        <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
        <AVAILABLE>NO</AVAILABLE>
    </SHOPITEM>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <CATEGORY>Full</CATEGORY>
        <WHEEL>27.5</WHEEL>
        <FRAMESIZE>LG</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>032,01</CODE>
        <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
        <COLOR>black / white</COLOR>

        <NOTE>Available 15.2.2015</NOTE>
        <URL></URL>
        <IMGURL1></IMGURL1>
        <IMGURL2></IMGURL2>
        <IMGURL3></IMGURL3>
        <PRICE>3199.99</PRICE>
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>


        <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
        <AVAILABLE>NO</AVAILABLE>
    </SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```

It is possible to group product options on same `<PRODUCT>`, like this:

```
<SHOPITEM>
    <CATEGORY>Full</CATEGORY>
    <WHEEL>27.5</WHEEL>
    <FRAMESIZE>LG</FRAMESIZE>
    <CODE>032,01</CODE>
    <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
    <COLOR>black / white</COLOR>

<NOTE>Available 15.2.2015</NOTE>
<URL></URL>
<IMGURL1></IMGURL1>
<IMGURL2></IMGURL2>
<IMGURL3></IMGURL3>
<PRICE>3199.99</PRICE>
<CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
<YEAR>2015</YEAR>
<AVAILABLE>NO</AVAILABLE>

<PRODUCT_VARIANT id="2">
    <COLOR>red / green</COLOR>
    <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
    <CODE>032,99</CODE>
    <IMGURL1></IMGURL1>
    <IMGURL2></IMGURL2>
    <IMGURL3></IMGURL3>
    <AVAILABLE>NO</AVAILABLE>
    <NOTE>Available 15.2.2015</NOTE>
</PRODUCT_VARIANT>
<PRODUCT_VARIANT id="3">
    <COLOR>black / white</COLOR>
    <FRAMESIZE>LG</FRAMESIZE>
    <CODE>032,01</CODE>
    <IMGURL1></IMGURL1>
    <IMGURL2></IMGURL2>
    <IMGURL3></IMGURL3>
    <AVAILABLE>NO</AVAILABLE>
        <NOTE>Available 15.2.2015</NOTE>
    </PRODUCT_VARIANT>
</SHOPITEM>
```

Comment: In your output, why are some elements included in the `PRODUCT_VARIANT` and some are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: This is based on the assumption that the shopitems should be grouped based on same  values of the `<PRODUCT>` child node. In case other node values have to be compared, please add this to the question.

The following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
    omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[not(PRODUCT=preceding-sibling::SHOPITEM/PRODUCT)]">
    <xsl:variable name="currentProduct" select="PRODUCT"/>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
          <xsl:if test="following-sibling::SHOPITEM[PRODUCT=$currentProduct]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::SHOPITEM
                         [PRODUCT=$currentProduct]" mode="variant"/>
           </xsl:if>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM" mode="variant">
  <xsl:variable name="currentProduct" select="PRODUCT"/>
    <PRODUCT_VARIANT>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::SHOPITEM/PRODUCT
                                [.=$currentProduct]) + 1"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </PRODUCT_VARIANT>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[PRODUCT=preceding-sibling::SHOPITEM/PRODUCT]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to your input XML generates the desired output.

The template

```
<xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[not(PRODUCT=preceding-sibling::SHOPITEM/PRODUCT)]">
```

copies all `SHOPITEM` nodes that have a `PRODUCT` child node that was no child of preceding shopitems. If this `SHOPITEM` has following sibling with the same `PRODUCT`

```
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::SHOPITEM[PRODUCT=$currentProduct]">
```

these are copied as variant using the

```
<xsl:template match="SHOPITEM" mode="variant">
```

This template creates the element `<PRODUCT_VARIANT>` and sets as attribute `id` the count of all preceding products with the same value as the product of the current `SHOPITEM` + 1:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::SHOPITEM/PRODUCT
                                [.=$currentProduct]) + 1"/>
```

The template matching

```
<xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[PRODUCT=preceding-sibling::SHOPITEM/PRODUCT]"/>
```

is empty and removes the `SHOPITEM` nodes that have already been written as variants.

**Update:** For the question in the comment if it's possible to add the `CODE` as `PRIMARY_CODE` to each variant - following adjusted XSLT

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[not(PRODUCT=preceding-sibling::SHOPITEM/PRODUCT)]">
    <xsl:variable name="currentProduct" select="PRODUCT"/>
    <xsl:variable name="currentCode" select="CODE"/>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::SHOPITEM[PRODUCT=$currentProduct]">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::SHOPITEM
                     [PRODUCT=$currentProduct]" mode="variant">
             <xsl:with-param name="code" select="$currentCode"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM" mode="variant">
    <xsl:param name="code"/>
    <xsl:variable name="currentProduct" select="PRODUCT"/>
    <PRODUCT_VARIANT>
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::SHOPITEM/PRODUCT
                            [.=$currentProduct]) + 1"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <PRIMARY_CODE>
        <xsl:value-of select="$code"/>
      </PRIMARY_CODE>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </PRODUCT_VARIANT>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[PRODUCT=preceding-sibling::SHOPITEM/PRODUCT]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

generates the desired output, just the relevant part:

```
<PRODUCT_VARIANT id="2">
  <PRIMARY_CODE>032,00</PRIMARY_CODE>
  <CATEGORY>Full</CATEGORY>
  ...
```

The adjustment is just to set the  `<xsl:variable name="currentCode" select="CODE"/>` in the template matching `SHOPITEM` and then apply the templates `mode="variant"` with the `currentCode` as parameter:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::SHOPITEM
                     [PRODUCT=$currentProduct]" mode="variant">
  <xsl:with-param name="code" select="$currentCode"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

In the `<xsl:template match="SHOPITEM" mode="variant">` the parameter is added as `<xsl:param name="code"/>` and simply written as

```
<PRIMARY_CODE><xsl:value-of select="$code"/></PRIMARY_CODE>
```

after the `<PRODUCT_VARIANT>`.

For convenience, I saved this here: http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2Cd

Comment: I don't think this does produce the desired output. If you notice, the 2 variants don't retain all of the original data. It also puts the variants outside of the `SHOPITEM` and the `id` attribute is incorrect (starts at `1` instead of `2`).

Comment: @DanielHaley Thanks for considering, this was based on the assumption mentioned in OP that it should be based on same `<PRODUCT>`, and I  understood this as matching the same value for `<PRODUCT>`. I'll update this in the answer as maybe all values have to be compared.

Comment: You might be right though; there doesn't seem to be any reason why some nodes are included in the variant and why some are not.

Comment: [The previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969885/merge-entries-in-xml) might help to clear things up - also @DanielHaley. Unfortunately, the OP did not link to it.

Comment: @DanielHaley And you were right that my first answer didn't match the required output as the variants were outside of the `SHOPITEM` -  thanks for that, I've it just adjusted.

Comment: You're welcome; +1. Thanks for the link. I already posted an answer, but I will go look at that question. I also see now that your answer was accepted, so you must've been right! :-)

Comment: @DanielHaley More than one `user[contains(name(),'Mat') and contains(name(),'hias')]` in the XSLT tag is confusing, isn't it? :-)

Comment: @matthias_h, with this updated code <product_variant> is badly generated: http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKw7 . Thanks you very much.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - Sorry! You're right, I didn't read past `mat`. I need to slow down ;-)

Comment: @Adrian There seems to be a mistake, just saved my updated code here: http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKw7/1 and have just corrected the adjustment of the `mode="variant"` in my answer.

Comment: @matthias_h it's work really well, thank you. I promise you that I will learn more about XLST. :)

Comment: @matthias_h a little question: Is there an easy way to add the primary <CODE> to the <PRODUCT_VARIANT> section as <PRIMARY_CODE>?Like here: http://bit.ly/1GI1veb

Comment: @Adrian Yes,  I've just updated my answer with an adjustment.

Comment: @matthias_h Thanks for coming back. :) Which is actually not working that PRIMARY_CODE is now = actual product code. An image tells more: http://bit.ly/1yZ693O In this case PRIMARY_CODE should be 032,00.

Comment: @Adrian I had it actually working in the first adjusted version (using the shopitem code as param for the variant) and then edited it to the non-working version as by mistake I thought the code of the variant would be the same (was in a hurry :) ). I've just rolled back to the first working version, so the primary code of the variant is now the code of the shopitem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option that uses `xsl:key`...

**XML Input**

```
<SHOP>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <CATEGORY>Full</CATEGORY>
        <WHEEL>27.5</WHEEL>
        <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>032,00</CODE>
        <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
        <COLOR>black / white</COLOR>
        <NOTE>Available 15.2.2015</NOTE>
        <URL></URL>
        <IMGURL1></IMGURL1>
        <IMGURL2></IMGURL2>
        <IMGURL3></IMGURL3>
        <PRICE>3199.99</PRICE>
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
        <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
        <AVAILABLE>NO</AVAILABLE>
    </SHOPITEM>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <CATEGORY>Full</CATEGORY>
        <WHEEL>27.5</WHEEL>
        <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>032,99</CODE>
        <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
        <COLOR>red / green</COLOR>
        <NOTE>Available 15.2.2015</NOTE>
        <URL></URL>
        <IMGURL1></IMGURL1>
        <IMGURL2></IMGURL2>
        <IMGURL3></IMGURL3>
        <PRICE>3199.99</PRICE>
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
        <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
        <AVAILABLE>NO</AVAILABLE>
    </SHOPITEM>
    <SHOPITEM>
        <CATEGORY>Full</CATEGORY>
        <WHEEL>27.5</WHEEL>
        <FRAMESIZE>LG</FRAMESIZE>
        <CODE>032,01</CODE>
        <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
        <COLOR>black / white</COLOR>
        <NOTE>Available 15.2.2015</NOTE>
        <URL></URL>
        <IMGURL1></IMGURL1>
        <IMGURL2></IMGURL2>
        <IMGURL3></IMGURL3>
        <PRICE>3199.99</PRICE>
        <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
        <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
        <AVAILABLE>NO</AVAILABLE>
    </SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="products" match="SHOPITEM" use="PRODUCT"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/SHOP">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="SHOPITEM[generate-id() = generate-id(key('products',PRODUCT)[1])]">
                <SHOPITEM>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/*/SHOPITEM[key('products',PRODUCT)]">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </SHOPITEM>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[position()=1]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM">
        <PRODUCT_VARIANT>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:number/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </PRODUCT_VARIANT>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<SHOP>
   <SHOPITEM>
      <CATEGORY>Full</CATEGORY>
      <WHEEL>27.5</WHEEL>
      <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
      <CODE>032,00</CODE>
      <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
      <COLOR>black / white</COLOR>
      <NOTE>Available 15.2.2015</NOTE>
      <URL/>
      <IMGURL1/>
      <IMGURL2/>
      <IMGURL3/>
      <PRICE>3199.99</PRICE>
      <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
      <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
      <AVAILABLE>NO</AVAILABLE>
      <PRODUCT_VARIANT id="2">
         <CATEGORY>Full</CATEGORY>
         <WHEEL>27.5</WHEEL>
         <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
         <CODE>032,99</CODE>
         <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
         <COLOR>red / green</COLOR>
         <NOTE>Available 15.2.2015</NOTE>
         <URL/>
         <IMGURL1/>
         <IMGURL2/>
         <IMGURL3/>
         <PRICE>3199.99</PRICE>
         <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
         <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
         <AVAILABLE>NO</AVAILABLE>
      </PRODUCT_VARIANT>
      <PRODUCT_VARIANT id="3">
         <CATEGORY>Full</CATEGORY>
         <WHEEL>27.5</WHEEL>
         <FRAMESIZE>LG</FRAMESIZE>
         <CODE>032,01</CODE>
         <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
         <COLOR>black / white</COLOR>
         <NOTE>Available 15.2.2015</NOTE>
         <URL/>
         <IMGURL1/>
         <IMGURL2/>
         <IMGURL3/>
         <PRICE>3199.99</PRICE>
         <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
         <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
         <AVAILABLE>NO</AVAILABLE>
      </PRODUCT_VARIANT>
   </SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```

This differs from your desired output in that it contains all of the original children of `SHOPITEM` for the variants. Here's a modified version that only retains the elements that are different from the first `SHOPITEM` in the group:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="products" match="SHOPITEM" use="PRODUCT"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/SHOP">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="SHOPITEM[generate-id() = generate-id(key('products',PRODUCT)[1])]">
                <SHOPITEM>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/*/SHOPITEM[key('products',PRODUCT)]">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </SHOPITEM>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[position()=1]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM">
        <PRODUCT_VARIANT>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:number/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="variant"/>
        </PRODUCT_VARIANT>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM/*" mode="variant">
        <xsl:if test="not(key('products',../PRODUCT)[1]/*[name()=name(current())]=.)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>                    
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<SHOP>
   <SHOPITEM>
      <CATEGORY>Full</CATEGORY>
      <WHEEL>27.5</WHEEL>
      <FRAMESIZE>MD</FRAMESIZE>
      <CODE>032,00</CODE>
      <PRODUCT>POINT</PRODUCT>
      <COLOR>black / white</COLOR>
      <NOTE>Available 15.2.2015</NOTE>
      <URL/>
      <IMGURL1/>
      <IMGURL2/>
      <IMGURL3/>
      <PRICE>3199.99</PRICE>
      <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
      <YEAR>2015</YEAR>
      <AVAILABLE>NO</AVAILABLE>
      <PRODUCT_VARIANT id="2">
         <CODE>032,99</CODE>
         <COLOR>red / green</COLOR>
      </PRODUCT_VARIANT>
      <PRODUCT_VARIANT id="3">
         <FRAMESIZE>LG</FRAMESIZE>
         <CODE>032,01</CODE>
      </PRODUCT_VARIANT>
   </SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```